# Python Selenium invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I updated webdriver-manager and undetect driver because I couldn't read the entire log (only INFO level). Now I'm receiving this error that I can't explain

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: log type 'performance' not found
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.198)
```

I read other answers on Stack Overflow and I tried using:

```
desired_capabilities['goog:perfLoggingPrefs'] = {'enableNetwork': True}
```

However, with this new setting, it doesn't read any lines of the log either

```
import json
import time

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  


class Network:

   def __init__(self):

       opts = uc.ChromeOptions()
       opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
       desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
       #desired_capabilities['goog:perfLoggingPrefs'] = {'enableNetwork': True}
       desired_capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"performance": "ALL"}


       opts.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
       opts.add_argument(f"--user-agent=Lynx: Lynx/2.8.8pre.4 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/2.12.23")
       self.driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts,
                            desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)

   def get_log(self):
       self.driver.get("https://streamingcommunity.codes/watch/4826")
       time.sleep(15)  # waiting for the page to load
       for log in self.driver.get_log("performance"):
           message = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
           if "Network.responseReceived" == message["method"]:
                url = message['params']['response']['url']
                print(url)
       self.driver.quit()


network = Network()
network.get_log()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set it with the `ChromeOptions`

```
opts.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
self.driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)
```

`desired_capabilities` parameter is deprecated in Selenium 4 and is removed in [version 4.10](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e#diff-5a60156e0c8a7c920aa161d26581ca3461625b9ea29c059bae02999fd388f22f).

Comment: Thank you The issue with the error has been resolved, but I'm facing the previous problem again, which is that it doesn't read the entire log, only a portion of it ( and I can see log level set to INFO..). In fact, I'm unable to read all the URLs with Python, whereas it is possible using the browser's web tools

Comment: @ghost239 the logs are generator, which means `get_log` will return only the logs from the last time you read them. If you want history append the results to a static list every time.

Comment: When I run the program, shouldn't I see the log of the link that I just used ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647947/selenium-4-10-does-not-set-the-log-level-to-all

Comment: @ghost239 of the requests since the driver navigated to the page. Try without the `if` just to see if you get the results.

Comment: Already printed the log variable. It prints many lines except for some of the links I'm searching for. It also prints {'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":.... The "INFO" should be "ALL"...

Comment: @ghost239 it's possible it might take some time, when I'm waiting for network requests I'm using a loop `end_time = time.time() + 10; while time.time() < end_time: search_for_call(); time.sleep(1);`

Comment: I understand, but if you want to try it yourself with the web link you find in the code, I'm not sure you will be able to obtain this link from the log: " " # h t t p s://scws.work/v2/playlist/107576?type=video&rendition=720p&.... ecc " when printed by Python. However, it is feasible with the browser's web tools.   here you can find the stackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647947/selenium-4-10-does-not-set-the-log-level-to-all