# Selenium 4.10 does not set the log level to ALL

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem where Selenium doesn't read the entire log but only a part of it. In fact, I'm unable to read all the URLs using Python, which is possible with the browser's web tools.
I think the problem is that it's not possible to set the log level. If I print the entire log, I get an INFO message on each line

```
    {'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.requestWillBeSent","params":




import json
import time

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class Network:

    def __init__(self):

        opts = uc.ChromeOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        opts.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
        opts.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        opts.add_argument(f"--user-agent=Lynx: Lynx/2.8.8pre.4 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/2.12.23")
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=opts)

def get_log(self):
        self.driver.get("")
        time.sleep(15)  # waiting for the page to load
        for log in self.driver.get_log("performance"):
           print(log)
           message = json.loads(log["message"])["message"]
           if "Network.responseReceived" == message["method"]:
               url = message['params']['response']['url']
               print(url)
        self.driver.quit()


network = Network()
network.get_log()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution with the assistance of the manual

```
def __init__(self):
    opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    opts.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    opts.add_argument(f"--user-agent=Lynx: Lynx/2.8.8pre.4 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/2.12.23")
    opts.page_load_strategy = 'normal'

    service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                                               options=opts,
                                               service_args=['--log-level=ALL', '--append-log'],
                                               log_path='LOGCHROME.txt')

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

def get_log(self):
    self.driver.get("")
    self.driver.quit()


network = Network()
network.get_log()
```